# SSH.NET > SSH client for port forwarding

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh.net

I'm using SSH.NET for coding an GUI to create a connection to a VPS. My intention is to make a proxy server for playing online games.

I need to forward a port dynamically, to create a SOCKS Server and then, Proxifier (another program installed on my computer) can connect to this server.

When I use PuTTY, Proxifier works well, but when I use my software, it's not working.

This is my code:

```
using (client = new SshClient("VPS_IP", "USER", "PASSWORD"))
{
    client.KeepAliveInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);

    client.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 50);

    port = new ForwardedPortDynamic("127.0.0.1", portNumber);
    client.Connect();
    client.AddForwardedPort(port);

    port.Start();

    if (client.IsConnected && port.IsStarted)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connected");
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20 * 1000);
}
```

And now, the log of Proxifier

```
[48:51] Testing Started.
Proxy Server
Address:    127.0.0.1:port
Protocol:   SOCKS 5
Authentication: NO

[48:51] Starting: Test 1: Connection to the Proxy Server
[48:51] IP Address: 127.0.0.1
[48:51] Connection established
[48:51] Test passed.
[48:51] Starting: Test 2: Connection through the Proxy Server
[48:51] Authentication was successful.
[48:51] Error : connection to the proxy server was closed unexpectedly.
[48:51] Test failed.
[48:51] Testing Finished.
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug problems with forwarded port, start by handling `ForwardedPort.Exception` event.

Once you find out what exception, if any, is raised, we can help you further.